# Selecting the most optimal query

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have table in Oracle database which is called my_table for example. It is type of log table. It has an *incremental* column which is named "id" and "registration_number" which is *unique* for registered users. Now I want to get latest changes for registered users so I wrote queries below to accomplish this task:

**First version:**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
WHERE t.id =
  (SELECT MAX(id) FROM my_table t_m WHERE t_m.registration_number = t.registration_number
  );
```

**Second version:**

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT MAX(id) m_id FROM my_table GROUP BY registration_number
  ) t_m
ON t.id = t_m.m_id;
```

My first question is which of above queries is recommended and why? And second one is if sometimes there is about 70.000 insert to this table but mostly the number of inserted rows is changing between 0 and 2000 is it reasonable to add index to this table?

Answer (score 2):

An analytical query might be the fastest way to get the latest change for each registered user:

```
SELECT registration_number, id
FROM (
  SELECT
    registration_number,
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY registration_number ORDER BY id DESC) AS IDRankByUser
  FROM my_table
)
WHERE IDRankByUser = 1
```

As for indexes, I'm assuming you already have an index by `registration_number`. An additional index on `id` will help the query, but maybe not by much and maybe not enough to justify the index. I say that because if you're inserting 70K rows at one time the additional index will slow down the `INSERT`. You'll have to experiment (and check the execution plans) to figure out if the index is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually at first I did this using ROW_NUMBER() but then I thought it is not the best way so I have tried other ways to do this. Why do think that it might be faster?

Comment: I have tested it but it is slower. Thank you for your time and recommendation on indexes

Comment: i can think of a scenario that the `max` query will be faster - if oracle uses `min/max scan` on the index. but you got a group by there and i'm not sure oracle can perform an min/max scan on a composite index. worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check for faster query, you should check the execution plan and cost and it will give you a fair idea. But i agree with solution of Ed Gibbs as analytics make query run much faster.
 If you feel this table is going to grow very big then i would suggest partitioning the table and using local indexes. They will definitely help you to form faster queries.

In cases where you want to insert lots of rows then indexes slow down insertion as with each insertion index also has to be updated[I will not recommend index on ID]. There are 2 solutions i have think of for this:

1. You can drop index before insertion and then recreate it after insertion.
2. Use reverse key indexes. Check this link : http://oracletoday.blogspot.in/2006/09/there-is-option-to-create-index.html. Reverse key index can impact your query a bit so there will be trade off.

Comment: Thank you for your advise on indexes I will try to implement that. But, unfortunately query which uses ROW_NUMBER() is slowest one among them

Answer (score 0):

If you look for faster solution and there is a really need to maintain list of last activity for each user, then most robust solution is to maintain separate table with unique `registration_number` values and `rowid` of last record created in log table.

E.g. (only for demo, not checked for syntax validity, sequences and triggers omitted):

```
create table my_log(id number not null, registration_number number, action_id varchar2(100))
/

create table last_user_action(refgistration_number number not null, last_action rowid)
/

alter table last_user_action 
  add constraint pk_last_user_action primary key (registration_number) using index 
/

create or replace procedure write_log(p_reg_num number, p_action_id varchar2)
is
  v_row_id rowid;
begin

  insert into my_log(registration_number, action_id) 
  values(p_reg_num, p_action_id)
  returning rowid into v_row_id;

  update last_user_action 
  set last_action = v_row_id 
  where registration_number = p_reg_num;

end;
/
```

With such schema you can simple query last actions for every user with good performance:

```
select 
from
  last_user_action lua,
  my_log           l
where
  l.rowid (+) = lua.last_action
```

Rowid is physical storage identity directly addressing storage block and you can't use it after moving to another server, restoring from backups etc. But if you need such functionality it's simple to add `id` column from `my_log` table to `last_user_action` too, and use one or another depending on requirements.